# Sending POST Request to Server with Volley Android

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I have a login screen in my app. I want to retrieve the phone number from the input field and send it to my backend server as a post request with volley. The backend server is structured this way:

```
"user": {
    "phone": 909099999
 }
```

I have tried this block of code:

```
final String phone = login_phoneTET.getText().toString();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("phone", phone);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
           Constants.TING_OTP_ENDPOINT,
           new JSONObject(params), 
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Success");
           }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed with an Error" + error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
           }
           }
        ) {
           @Override
           public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
          }
       };

    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    VolleySingleton.getVolleySingleton(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

and also tried using a string request. I keep getting this error in logcat:

```
E/Volley: [22489] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://:):)/api/user/generateOTP
```

Am I making this request properly or is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's a server side error. So i think you need to be concern about your server.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could it be int to string or vice versa type conversion error?

Comment: May be not. Actually it's quite difficult to answer without seeing code. If you post here related code then it will be easy to try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json's(the one you send, and the one you get back).

if the JSON you wrote, is the one you are sending:

```
"user": {
"phone": 909099999}
```

then its not a valid JSON, and there is your error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
"user": {   "phone": 909099
------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
```